# How to set object that is being refereed in private inner class while creating Junit?

Tags: java, junit, constructor, powermock

I have 2 java classes.

```
1) class1.java

public class class1
{
  private class ParameterVariable
  {
   class2 c1;
   String s;
   ParameterVariable(String s)
   {
        this.s =s;
   }
  }


   public void methodToTest(String s)
   {
        try
        {
            ParameterVariable pv = new ParameterVariable(s)
            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pv.c1.getPartNo()))
            {
               // Some Code
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        // Some code
        }


   }
}

2) class2.java
public class class2
{
    // pojo class
    String partNo;
    public String getPartNo()
    {
        return partNo;
    }
    public void setPartNo(String partNo)
    {
        this.partNo = partNo;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a Junit test case for my method. I am not able to get runtime value for class2 object.
Here is my work

```
private class1 = null;

protected Object createParamterVariableObject ( String s ) throws ClassNotFoundException,  InstantiationException, 
                                                                                                                    IllegalAccessException,  InvocationTargetException, 
                                                                                                                    NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
{
    Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(class1.class, "ParameterVariable");
    Constructor constructorForParameterVariable = clazz.getConstructor(String.java)

    Object parameterVariableObject = constructorForParameterVariable.newInstance(String.java)
    return parameterVariableObject;
}

@Test
public void junitTestCase() throws Exception 
{
  String s = "Sample";
  Class clazz = null;
    Object parameterVariableObject = null;
  class2 cls2Object = new clsObject;

    try
    {
        parameterVariableObject = createParamterVariableObject(s);

        clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(SupersedeImpl.class, "ParameterVariable");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    class2 c2Object = new class2();
    c2Object.setPartNo("NEW_PART_NO");
    Field C1Field = (Field) parameterVariableObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1");
    C1Field.set(parameterVariableObject, C1Field);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(clazz).withArguments(s).thenReturn(parameterVariableObject);

    class1 = PowerMockito.spy(class1);

    class1.methodToTest(s);

    // some assertion
}
```

I want to set some mocking value of part no that is object of class2. 
Because my method is based on it.
I am getting null using these code. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by mocking the object class2 c1,
in your code there must be setter method that is injecting the object.
You can use that in you JUnit test case to return the mock object.
i.e. via doReturn().. when()..
After that you will get the mocked object in your code.
you can use when().. then() for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: make your life easier:

- Change that **inner** class to a normal class
- Create a **factory** that returns instances of that class

And then use **dependency injection** to give such a factory to your class under test. And use any ordinary mocking framework to create those objects.

Done. And not only do you avoid all those issues that complicate mocking in your version; you also end up with code that is less tightly coupled.